# Encrypt data in web.config

Tags: vb.net, web-config, asp.net-3.5

I have the following line in my web.config

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="AdminPassword" value="ASDF1234" />
</appSettings>
```

How can I encrypt it? I tried this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043331/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx) but it got me all confused

Help?!

Comment: Scott Mitchell's articles are amongst the easiest to understand. so I think you may be out of luck...

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand? Specific Questions/problems are much easier to talk about rather then a general "don't know how to..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the articles at: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx

Comment: I actually had to do this the other day.  It is extremely simple to encypt your web.config.